# As tags [tuple] e [tupla] deveriam ser sinônimas?

Tags: debate, tags, tags-sinônimas

Essas tags descritas abaixo:

- [tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tupla)

  > Em Python tuplas são uma estrutura de dados que funcionam como uma
  >   list, mas são imutáveis.
- [tuple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuple)

  > A tag *tuple* não possui recomendações de uso, você poderia ajudar-nos a
  >   criá-las?

A tag [tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tupla) tem 8 perguntas: 7 de [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) e uma de [swift](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift). Já a tag [tuple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuple) tem 3 perguntas: 2 em [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) e 1 em [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

A minha sugestão é transformá-las em sinônimos e mudar para uma descrição geral que não dependa de nenhuma linguagem.

O que acham?

Comment: Acho que é só uma questão de decidir qual deve sobreviver.

Comment: @bigown Não entendi se você está concordando e "sobreviver" se refere à tag a ser eleita como principal, ou se propõe eliminar uma delas.

Comment: @bfavaretto estou quase concordando, espero opiniões, mas esse caso parece que é a mesma coisa. Mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: Eu tornaria a versão em EN sinônima da versão em PT. Remover uma delas deixa margem pra que ressurja.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo, acho que se deveria fazer sempre isso, assim acabavam os problemas dessas tags.

Comment: Alguém pode sugerir? Concordo em deixar a versão EN como principal.

Comment: @vnbrs acho que a descrição da TAG também esta ruim, dá a entender que só Python tem tuplas, já que existe em c++ também (e talvez em uma ou outra linguagem), eu só não sei afirmar se tem o mesmo propósito.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento criei uma pergunta para isso agora https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6560/a-tag-tupla-é-só-para-python :P

Answer (score 2):

Concordo com a questão do sinônimo como o AP e o bfavaretto citaram. Mas, seguindo o exemplo de outras tags que temos, sugiro manter a tag em português como principal.

A descrição dela pode ser corrigida quando chegarmos a um consenso na outra pergunta: 
[A tag [tupla] é só para Python ou deveria abarcar um conceito mais amplo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6560/)