# A tag [tupla] é só para Python ou deveria abarcar um conceito mais amplo?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Assim diz o fragmento de recomendação da tag [tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tupla):

> Em Python tuplas são uma estrutura de dados que funcionam como uma list, mas são imutáveis.

Deveria ser exclusiva do Python mesmo ou a recomendação está errada?

As tuplas (ou [enuplas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enupla)) são estruturas [matemáticas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) e existem implementações em diversos contextos, como [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) e [C++](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), não só [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: Penso que esta errada, já que existe em outras linguagens como c++, mas como não domino, só conheço mais em Python mesmo vou deixar para outras pessoas cuidarem disto :) - Vnbrs obrigado pela grande colaboração no Meta!

Comment: Editei e coloquei mais linguagens que conheço e tem essa estrutura. Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento :)

Comment: Tupla é um conceito matemático. Como se fosse um "conjunto ordenado". Por exemplo, coordenadas em um plano cartesiano são 2-uplas de números reais, coordenadas nas três dimensões são 3-uplas de números reais também. Tuplas não precisam ser homogêneas também, então posso ter em um conjunto tuplas compostas por letra e inteiro, conjunto esse que representa uma palavra. Portanto, a recomendação está errada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado resumindo tudo o que eu entendi, talvez a tag tupla nem deveria existir, já que é característica de algumas linguagens e pode variar, bastaria a tag da linguagem. O que acha?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento para mim o conceito matemático faz sentido _per si_, independente de linguagem. E ele é constante. Eu sei que aqui tem partes matemáticas destacadas, como expressões booleanas eu acho. Não sei quando algo mereceria um destaque a parte aqui no SOpt

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que começo a entender porque até hoje [isto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5415/3635) não foi resolvido. Vamos aguardar mais um pouco então :)

Comment: Python usa tuplas, mas tuplas não pertence ao python. Uma linha de uma tabela no banco de dados é uma tupla...Indo diretamente a questão, acho que a descrição deve ser mais ampla

Answer (score 1):

Eu concordo em mudar para uma descrição geral que não dependa de nenhuma linguagem.

O raciocínio é o mesmo já utilizado para outras tags como *classes, funções, variáveis, etc*... Nenhuma dessas tags que representam conceitos são presas a uma linguagem específica.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não deve ser um conceito exclusivo do Python, inclusive nesse próprio fragmento da recomendação da tag já o descreve como um conceito que existe em Python mas não é exclusivo ao mesmo ao escrever "**Em Python** tuplas[...]".